# Keeping active states in css

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a log in form and I am doing hide/show states in JavaScript.

Is there a way that when I load the page, the first button is on active state, while when I click anoother button it becomes active and the previous one is no longer active?

My HTML:

```
<a class="login-button" >login</a><a class="login-button">register</a><a class="login-button">cant login?</a>
```

My CSS:

```
.login-button
{color:#00BFFF;
padding-right:20px;
}
.login-button:active
{ color:#FFF;
font-family:customfont-bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use JavaScript as @Sachin point out, or do it in **pure CSS** making use of the `:target` pseudoclass.

The only thing you should do is to add a hyperlink reference (`href`) to your anchor tag, which, I think, would make your markup more semantic.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#login" id="login" class="login-button">login</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#login:target {
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:customfont-bold;
}
```

Since you taget your question just as [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)/[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) I thought a CSS solution would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript or Jquery to achieve this. Here is sample for you

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

CSS

```
.active
{ 
  color:#FFF;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

of-course you can use selector more specifically.

Comment: the first one stays blue and it dosent change

Comment: first one means? you active class has white color. So active link would be white.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the class that u want to appear active at first to `class="login-button active"`

Then insert a javascript function to change from one to another, for example:

```
function{ 
      var element = document.getElementsByClassName("login-button active");
      element.className="login-button";
}
```

You could also add some `id=""` in order to make easier the changes. Then u can use:

`var element = document.getElementById("yourID");`